# Objective-c SDK for ios application to analyse the number of active users load the application

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there are any recommended SDK to analyse the number of active user of my ios application. I need to analyse the number of users load the application per day and also it would be great if we able to analyse the maximum use of functionality in the application(For example like if the application as 10 functionality and the active users most often use the 5 out of 10 functionality).

Comment: You'd have to get your app to communicate with a central service and let the service do that sort of thing.  This would only work for users with internet access of course.

Comment: Use Google Analytics SDK for that. Its pretty simple to use

Comment: There are tons of analytics libraries out there, all with their own advantages and drawbacks. So there isn't a "right" answer to this question. For that reason, it will probably be closed.

Answer (score 2):

`Flurry` SDK fits your case the best, easy to integrate and to use.

http://www.flurry.com/

[Here is nice tutorial how to use it](http://surgeworks.com/blog/lab-mobile/iphone/how-to-implement-flurry-analytics-in-iphone-app)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!! Let me check..

Comment: Also i want to add that Flurry manages number of active users and a lot of other features itself, and you event do not need to implement it..

Comment: Definately flurry, it monitors not only how many time the app has been run, but also their region and how the users use the app. In addition, it monitors all crashes;)

Comment: Great!! It would be helpful for me if I will be able to monitor crashes and the number of active users :)

Answer (score 0):

Flurry, Google Analytics, heatma.ps, Parse ...
There is really many features for analyse Applications.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/

http://www.flurry.com/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!! Let me check..

Answer (score 0):

Another choice is to use Quantcast Measure for Mobile Apps. Works great if multiple apps and websites and want to understand your users cross-platform.

https://www.quantcast.com/apps